# Print integer from array A based on array B integer?

Tags: c++, c++11

New to C++. I am looking for advise on the approach to this problem.

Given the following array:

**Array A**

```
1 21 43 54 99
```

**Array B**

```
1 4 5
```

**What I want to achieve:**

Array B integer is use to find the position of the value in array A. The end result, using the above two array, will be

**End result**

```
1 54 99
```

Where array B 1 will extract 1 from array A, array B 4 will extract out 54 from array A and so on. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Your example assumes that C++ arrays are indexed from one, but this is not true. C++ arrays are indexed from **zero**

Comment: Arrays start from index 0, not 1.  The way the question is worded doesn't stress this very fundamental aspect of C++ arrays.

Comment: Read some [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Take inspiration from existing C++ software on [github](http://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can iterate over `arrB` and get the desired values by doing the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int arrA[] = {1, 21, 43, 54, 99};
    int arrB[] = {1, 4, 5};

    // iterating over arrB
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << arrA[arrB[i] - 1] << ' ';
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Output :

```
1 54 99
```

Note :
Don't forget to add the required conditions (ensure accessing array within bounds) to escape from the undefined behavior.

Comment: Cool. Sorry silly question, could you explain on arrA[arrB[i]-1]? Is this consider a 2D array and why is there a need to '- 1'?

Comment: Arrays follow zero indexing and in your question, you are referring the 1st element using 1 (i.e we need to subtract 1 to achieve zero indexing).

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to define the array length when initializing the array. Secondly, avoid the usage of `using namespace std;`, thirdly, beautiful code. +1

Comment: @user3118602 No it's not a 2D array. It is using one array as an index to another, which is exactly what your questions asks for.

Comment: @RohanBari thanks, I was about to edit the code you just did that.

Comment: Now, if one of those values in `arrB` happens to be 0, watch what happens.